# Python - CSV to networkx format

Tags: python, networkx

I would like to create a network with networkx package from the data stored in the CSV. The data in the CSV file consist of two columns, as in example below. All nodes within the same edge group connects with each other (i.e. in E1 group (3 elements); there are: ABC -> BCD, BCD -> DEF, ABC -> DEF).

What would be the best approach/practice for transforming such data in Python to get an input for networkx package?

```
Edges   Nodes
E1      ABC
E1      BCD
E1      DEF
E2      ABC
E2      BCD
E3      ABC
E3      BCD
E3      CDE
E3      DEF
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your format seems rather awkward as a graph specification. Edges are dyadic in nature, i.e. they connect two nodes, but your definition has potential for an edge to be related to a single node.
Your example also includes more than one edge between the same pair of nodes (e.g. ABC -> BCD via E1 and E2).  This implies a MultiGraph.

IF this is really what your format should define, here is a way to get it into a networkx graph.  There are very likely cleaner ways to read the data.

```
import networkx as nx
import itertools

# read file into a dictionary, in 3 stages.
with open("graph.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

edges = []
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith('Edges'):
        continue
    parts = line.strip().split()
    edges.append(parts)

D = {}
for e, n in edges:
    if e not in D:
        D[e] = []
    D[e].append(n)

G = nx.MultiGraph()

# for each edge group, add edges between all pairs of nodes
for e, nodes in D.items():
    print e, nodes
    for (u,v) in itertools.combinations(nodes, 2):
        G.add_edge(u, v, label=e)
```